# Which platform should I use to code a mobile application?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, ipod-touch

I want to code a mobile application and need some guidance. I want to code an application that can do the following;

1. Take a picture.
2. Split the picture into 9 tiles
3. Randomly place the tiles on the screen.
4. Have the user unscramble the picture.

Now I don't know anything about mobile coding yet. So I would like to know form anyone who does, what is the best platform/framework to code this in and also is there an easy way to have this work on both iphone/ipod touch and android?

Thanks for any suggestion and guidance you can give me.

Answer (score 2):

Start [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) for android or [here](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) for mac. Going cross platform is not really possible as android works in java and mac works in objective-c. You can transfer your algorithms just fine, but you will have to rewrite your code from one platform to another.

Comment: Not completely true, there are tools today that allow one to program Android devices in C++, and mobile apps on apple products can be done in Objective-C++ where 99% of the code is almost directly transferable!

Answer (score 2):

Android applications are written in Java, and iPhone apps are written in Objective C.  There are some cross compilers but they are usually not very reliable.  The best way to write two separate apps individually.  Android Applications can be written in C or C++ using the NDK, but this still does requires you to write separate apps

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot more factors to look into other than what you want to do. For example, if you are more comfortable with certain programming languages or what you are willing to pay to develop. Generally, an iOS developer account will cost money (though you can download the sdk for free). If you are comfortable with C or any C variants, I recommend using iOS. If you are most comfortable with Java or OOP (Obect Oriented Programming), then use Android.

As for working with images, this is much simpler to do on iOS (many Android developers who work directly with bitmaps run out of memory quickly. iOS has some better built in methods here, and doesn't have the heap size limitation).

Lastly you should consider your audience. There is a better market for games on iOS, and more utility apps on Android. But obviously a good games is a good game, and people will buy it if you do a good job. As for cross-platforming, there are many tools or joint-languages that you can use, but for something so simple as this, I would recommend not wasting your time with those and go native for both OSes.